# Examples for $ \bar{A}\cap \bar{B}\neq\emptyset $, but $ \bar{A}\cap B=A\cap\bar{B}=\emptyset $.

Tags: general-topology

> Are there examples for sets $ A, B\subset X $, where $ X $ is a topological spacce and $ A, B $ are its nonempty subsets, satisfying $ \bar{A}\cap \bar{B}\neq\emptyset $, but $ \bar{A}\cap B=A\cap\bar{B}=\emptyset $.

I came up with this question when I was reading *Basic Topology*(M.A.Armstrong). I am trying to gain more intuitions about the difference between conditions for connectedness and separated from one another in $ X $.

> Note that a space $ X $ is **connected** if whenever it is decomposed as the union $ A\cup B $ of two nonempty subsests then $ \bar{A}\cap B\neq\emptyset $ or $ A\cap \bar{B}\neq\emptyset $.
>
> And if $ A $ and $ B $ are subsets of a space $ X $, and if $ \bar{A}\cap\bar{B} $ is empty, we say that $ A $ and $ B $ are **separated** from one another in $ X $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ordinary real line, let $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$, so that $1 \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

Comment: but $\overline{A}\bigcap B \not= \emptyset$

Comment: @JoelPereira how so?  $\overline{A}=[0,1]$.  What belongs to this as well as $(1,2)$, which consists of things **strictly bigger** than $1$?

Comment: oh i read it as "A complement" as opposed to cl(A). my fault.